# Генерация предложений из списка слов

Tags: python, список, комбинаторика

Скрипт на python генерит все комбинации предложений из списка слов перебором, но только не повторяющиеся слова в каждой строке (предложении). Как переделать код, чтобы выдавал все возможные комбинации, включая повторы слов (при заданном количестве слов)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from itertools import permutations
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentError

parser = ArgumentParser(
    description='Print all possible permutations of strings from a file'
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-f', '--file',
    help='file to read strings from'
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-min', '--minimum',
    help='minimal number of words in a single sentence'
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-max', '--maximum',
    help='maximal number of words in a single sentence'
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args.file:
        raise ArgumentError(args.file, C)

    with open(args.file) as f:
        strings = tuple(filter(None, f.read().splitlines()))

    minimum = int(args.minimum) or 1
    maximum = int(args.maximum) or len(strings)

    for length in range(minimum, maximum+1):
        for sentence in permutations(strings, length):
            print(' '.join(sentence))
```

Comment: Это что такое - ``minimum = int(args.minimum) or 1``? И следующая строчка.

Comment: скрипт содержит аргументы для задания минимального и макс. количества слов в строке, запускается к примеру так (количество слов от 1 до 8) `python3 script.py -f spisokslov.txt -min 1 -max 8`

Answer (score 2):

`permutations` выдает [перестановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) (т.е. сочетания без повторов). Чтобы получить все возможные [сочетания с повторами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) нужно использовать [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).