# Рандомный комбинируемый вывод требуемой длины строк из списка

Tags: python

Имеем текстовый файл вида:

```
foo
two word
bar
#
cat
tea - five o'clock
666
```

Это не обязательно слова, любые символы по сути, в одной строке может быть несколько слов, в т.ч. разделенных пробелами. Текстовый файл может быть большим и даже огромным - вплоть до сотен гигабайт или пары террабайт.

Что хочется: выдавать рандомно сочетания из подобного списка строк по требуемой длине количества строк списка (пример есть ниже)

Можно взять за основу этот 
[скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822225/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2).
Он выполняет все то, что нужно, но без рандомизации, то есть он выдает последовательный вывод строк, перебирая все варианты, начиная с первой строки, как генератор брутфорса, и имеет встроенную функцию выбора количества выводимых строк -запускается с флагами минимального и максимального вывода строк. 
Запускается так:`python3 script.py -f spisokslov.txt -min 2 -max 3`
и будет иметь вывод:

```
foo two word
foo bar
foo #
foo cat
foo tea - five o'clock
foo 666
two word foo
two word bar
two word #
* удалил тут часть строк для сокращения примера, и последняя строка:
666 tea - five o'clock cat
```

Скрипт вставляет по одному пробелу между строками, но после последнего слова в выводимой строке пробела нет. Это оптимально - при желании потом можно пробелы подавить в трубе.
Вообщем нужно все тоже самое, только прибавить сюда рандомный вывод, чтобы вывод был не последовательным, а хаотичным, но с тем же функционалом выбора кол-ва строк: `-min 2 -max 3`

```
tea - five o'clock two word
# foo
foo 666 #
cat foo two word 
bar tea - five o'clock
```

скрипт выдает только сочетания без дублей (если в самом текстовом файле их конечно нет), желательно это сохранить, но если с рандомом это сложно - то можно и без этого.

Как альтернативный вариант, можно использовать за основу принцип, как у утилит combinator.bin и combinator3.bin в наборе hashcat-utils от Kali linux - они перебирают, но тоже последовательно списки 2 или максимум из 3 файлов между собой:
`./combinator3.bin spisokslov1.txt spisokslov2.txt spisokslov3.txt`
[(тут -combinator3.c)](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat-utils/blob/master/src/combinator3.c)
Возможно это будет проще - создаем несколько разных отдельных текстовых файлов по количеству комбинируемых между собой сочетаний, и далее рандомно выбираем строку из первого списка, затем рандомно из второго и так далее, однако, тогда списки в случае больших занимают очень много места...

Если построение с минимальным и максимальным кол-вом строк усложняет, можно им пренебречь, достаточно тогда выбираемой одной фиксированной длины.
Скрипт должен иметь свой цикл выдачи строк, по сути на бесконечность или с указанием предельного количества выдаваемых строк.

В любом случае, буду рад любому рандомному варианту, если кто поможет. спасибо

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: Моей квалификации чайника не хватает, чтобы это переделать

Answer (score 1):

Имеется длинная последовательность `(A,B,C,D...)`

Нужно создать случайные комбинации длиной от Min до Max

Я предполагаю, что доступ к последовательности последовательный, а не произвольный,  так что выбор из случайного места затруднён (для выбора строки с определённым номером из очень длинного файла придётся перечитать весь файл до этого места либо хранить индексы).

Создадим список списков списков. Размерность по первому измерению Max+1. В списке верхнего уровня с индексом k хранятся списки списков с длиной самых внутренних списков k (назовём это списками ранга k).

Вначале имеем пустой список.
Идём по последовательности.
Выбираем очередной элемент с вероятностью q (или игнорируем его с вероятностью (1-q)). *(Если мы хотим создать все возможные комбинации (мириады), то q = 1)*

Теперь вставляем очередной элемент во все места имеющихся списков ранга ниже Max (в том числе и пустого) с вероятностью p. Если в список делается вставка, то сохраняется также его не изменённая копия, а новый список переносится к спискам более высокого ранга.

Например, один из имеющихся списков [C,A,B]. Вставка элемента X возможна в 4 места: [X,C,A,B], [C,X,A,B], [C,A,X,B], [C,A,B,X].

Если, кроме вставки, делать и замену ([C,A,B] => [C,X,B]), то распределение будет несколько другим, однако возможны дубликаты.

Пример генерации всех (т.е. вероятность выбор единичная) комбинаций длиной от 0 до 3 (здесь я списки по верхнему уровню не разделял, только отсортировал по рангу)

```
[]

[] [A]

[] [B] [A] [A,B] [B,A]

[] [C] [B] [A] [C,B] [B,C] [C,A] [A,C] [A,B] [B,A] 
                   [C,A,B] [A,C,B] [A,B,C] [C,B,A] [B,C,A] [B,A,C]
```

Третий этап как список списков списков:

```
[[[]], 
 [[C] [B] [A]],
 [[C,B] [B,C] [C,A] [A,C] [A,B] [B,A]], 
 [[C,A,B] [A,C,B] [A,B,C] [C,B,A] [B,C,A] [B,A,C]]]
```

**Edit**
Если предположение об произвольном доступе неверно, то достаточно рассчитать количество N комбинаций нужной длины, сгенерировать случайное число R в пределах N и вывести R-ю комбинацию.

Comment: вопрос пока не по существу Вашего ответа. Я указывал ссылку по combinator3.c на GitHub. Он видимо написано на С. Не знаю, реально это или нет, нельзя в его коде просто переправить так, чтобы он работал не только с тремя списками, но с нужным количеством? ибо в ряде случаев нужен такой функционал, а в ряде тот, который описан в этом вопросе.

Comment: Видимо, возможно (наверное, проще всего - рекурсивно), но код не комментирован. На Питоне будет проще написать с использованием `itertools.product`

Comment: нашел похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480219/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python?rq=1